# Highchart tooltip PointOptionsObject interface implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, tooltip

I'm passing extra fields(eg: color, data_status, data_oos, data_soc and data_status_cd) for Highchart apart from x, y and z.

```
x: timestamp,
y: soc,
z: duration,
color: color,
data_status: state,
data_oos: oosFg,
data_soc: soc,
data_status_cd: errorCode
```

My intention is to use these custom values in Highchart tooltip formatter function. I could not find a clear implementation example of Highchart PointOptionsObject for typescript in https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PointOptionsObject. Is there a way to access these values? Below is a part of formatter function I'm trying to use.

```
tooltip: {
          //useHTML: true,
          formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point,
            series = this.series,
            pointIndex = point.index,
            oos = point.options.data_oos,
            status = point.options.data_status,
            soc = point.options.data_soc,
            status_code = point.options.data_status_cd;

            const text = "<strong>Charging: " + status_code + " " + "| Out of Service</strong>";
            return text;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your code to some online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by implementing my own custom interface inherited by **PointOptionsObject**.

```
    interface Custom extends Highcharts.PointOptionsObject {
            data_state: number;
            data_oos: boolean;
            data_soc: number;
            data_status_cd: number;
            z: number;
            timeZone: string;
}
```

then I created an object of **Custom** and set it to *options* flag of **Point** data which I was able to access again from tooltop point as below.

```
        tooltip: {
                //useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    var custom = this.point.options as Custom; 
                    var [state, oos, statusCode, soc, text] = ["Not Connected", "", "", "", ""];
                statusCode = (custom.data_status_cd !== null) ? (": " + custom.data_status_cd + " ") : "";
...

    }
```